# Why is my FBX export translucent?

Tags: materials, export, transparency, customization, .fbx

All my FBX exports are coming out translucent, it adds normal and alpha maps where there isn't supposed to. Here's what I do:

1. Add a cube, give it a material with a “base color” texture:

[image]

2. Export as FBX. All my settings are default, except for the Path Mode, which is set to “Copy” and Embed Textures is turned on.

[image]

3. Create a new Blender file and import the FBX. Switch to Cycles, the model is translucent. You can see in the image that the imported model has an empty normal map, and the color texture is now also added as an alpha texture, which I did not do.

[image]

Why is this happening? How do I make it work correctly? I never had problems before with FBX but now every model I make is coming out like this.

Here are my test files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15dB-iESKis41PlqnJgupWVG9ShtxEqIp?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think the model is translucent, you just need to light the scene.

Comment: @EricXue It is translucent. Here is a comparison between the normal model (on the left) and the imported FBX (on the right): https://i.imgur.com/UK05T5k.png